# Android: device independent pixel

Tags: android, device, pixel, density-independent-pixel

I know using dip is good for compatibility to different screen devices. But I would like to ask i a tablet of 600*800 as an example with a text field of 600 dip fit to the screen. Does it still fit on on a 400*320 screen as well.

Comment: It will. And it will look fine.

Comment: Is there a different between dip or dp and what is sp different?

Comment: AFAIK dp and dip are the same, and sp is for text-size